# Organic aphid control on houseplants

Tags: home, gardening, pest-management, pesticides

What is the best option that's going to be safe for children/pets and require the least amount of reapplication?

I'm looking for something that has little to no phytotoxicity between plant species.

Comment: There's a similar question about [aphid control on roses](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/23/99).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spray the plants with soapy water; a natural vegetable-based soap will work fine (no more than about a tablespoon per 2 liters of water).  Make sure to spray the undersides of the leaves too.

However, do first check for ladybugs or other aphid predators; if there are any such predators present, there is no need to spray at all (and the soap would kill them too).

Comment: I'm going to go with the tea tree Dr. Bronners.